# not able to display listview , asynctask is used to download images in adapter

Tags: android-asynctask

I used Asynctask to download images, which is executed from the getview method of custom adapter. This custom adapter is set to a listview, but nothing is displayed in the listview.
I want to display the listview when clicked on the progress bar from main activity
what could be the problem? Please can anyone help me.
My code is like this :
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_image, null);
            imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            convertView.setTag(imageview);
            new DownloadTask().execute(images.get(position), imageview);                 
        }
        return convertView;
    }       
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Bitmap>{
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {         

        String url = (String) params[0];
        iv = (ImageView) params[1];     
        Bitmap bmap = null;

        try {               
            bmap = getBitmap(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
            return bmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String urlstring) throws IOException{

        URL _url = new URL(urlstring);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        iv.setImageBitmap(result);          

    }
```

progress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress.setVisibility(progress.GONE);
            adapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.show_image,imagenames); 

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
    });
```

Comment: Have you looked in your LogCat window?  Are you seeing any exceptions thrown?  Have you tried debugging and stopping at breakpoints in this code, to see **where** the code fails?  Please let us know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView; // Global variable
//not ImageView in Asynctask, iv = (ImageView) params[1];
```

in doInBackground

```
try {               
     publishProgress(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
     //...
}

@Override    
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... urlstring) {
    //do what you to in getBitmap
    //but not return it
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

You should use **onProgressUpdate**